# Wiring specific subclass of particular component field type (@SpringBootApplication and @Autowire)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a simple Spring application `AppMain` with autowiring where I'd like not to use any explicit XML configuration.

In my `TaskScheduler` component I'd like to wire `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` object to `taskExecutor` field that is of super-class type. Its something that is straightforward in Spring with XML.

But is it possible with autowiring and pure annotation based config? How to do that?

**AppMain**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AppMain.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

**TaskScheduler**

```
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class TaskScheduler {

    @Autowired 
    private final TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void checkConfiguration() {
        // TODO: do some business with task executor (expecting it to be ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in runtime)
    }
```

}

Comment: How about creating a constructor based injection? You should add @Autowire to the constructor instead of the field, and give in the super-class as input into the constructor.

Comment: Ah, ok, so something like: `@Autowired public TaskScheduler(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor; }` should do the trick... I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, you need a specific implementation (`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`) when you need wiring for `TaskExecutor`.

In that case you need to create a configuration class with a spring bean inside that builds the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and then import the configuration in your main application.

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

    @Configuration
    public class AppConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
            return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        }
    }
```

And then modify your main class like so :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Import(AppConfiguration.class)
public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AppMain.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `@Import(AppConfiguration.class)` necessary?

Comment: Yes, Spring will resolve dependencies based on component scanning and your configuration imports.